# Colored word-diff just like git's?

Tags: colors, git, diff, colordiff

I've been for long using git's (colored) `--word-diff` which I find awesome. I found myself today in a situation where I had two strings I needed to compare word by word and craving for something just like git's diff.

I am aware of `wdiff` + `colordiff`, but its results certainly aren't stellar:

```
me@me:~$ wdiff <(echo -e "abc\ndef") <(echo -e "dbcx\ndef") | colordiff
[-abc-]{+dbcx+}
def
```

Is there any better option around? I don't particularly like those `[-`, `-]` and `{+`, `+}`.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `git`'s own [diff-highlight](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/diff-highlight).  It can highlight word differences in unified `diff` output, and it can also cope with ANSI colors on input.  So you can do something like this:

```
colordiff -u <(echo -e "foo abc\ndef") <(echo -e "foo dbcx\ndef") | diff-highlight
```

Comment: That only works for the trivial case where there is a single word changed on the line.  When it gets multiple words changing, it incorrectly stretches the reverse-video across words which did not change:

`colordiff -u <(echo -e "foo abc x y\ndef") <(echo -e "foo dbcx x z\ndef") | diff-highlight`

Comment: @ThomasDickey It seems to need two words to re-synch.  Anyway, it _is_ what `git` does. _shrug_

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git diff` with the right option set:

```
git diff --no-index --word-diff --color-words <(echo -e "foo abc\ndef") <(echo -e "foo dbcx\ndef")
```

Comment: how I can view diff result from patch file  *.diff instead comparing two sources ? 
`cat rewrites.diff | colordiff -u`